# Name of the object C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor

is there a way to let the constructor of the object know its name?

I would like to have **string myObject.name** created by the constructor based on the actual name of the object. Is it possible?

```
myClass Example;
//constructor creates an object with this name and i would like to have Example.name=="Example";
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no way to do that in standard C++. And asking for this is often a sign of a design issue. Explain what your end goal is for that, and someone might give you a good way of implementing it.

Comment: (Well, there's horrible macro tricks you can use. But... that's ugly.)

Comment: I need to have this variable to show the user its value, but if there is not easy way to do this i will just type it manually and it also works. Thanks

Comment: Seems like what you need is a `std::map<std::string, myClass>` or a variation thereof.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables have names. Not all objects are connected with variables. You can't do that automatically in any case. You need to add an argument of type string to the constructor, and explicitly pass a string of your choosing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such inbuilt functionality.
Although you can build one for yourself, following is the one way how you can achieve it.

```
    class myClass {
       std::string m_objectName;
    public:
       myClass(std::string name):m_objectName(name);
       std::string name()
       {
           return m_objectName;
       }
    };
```

Now create object like this:

```
myClass Example("Example");
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no guarantee that it actually has a source name of any kind, so there's no sense in such a mechanism. And furthermore, tying your user display to the internal implementation details of your source code is a tremendously bad idea.

You, of course, can assign it whatever name you like that you think has whatever meaning you like.

Answer (score 0):

Not very useful, but with a macro you can achieve something near:

```
#define CREATE( a, b ) a b(b)

int main()
{
   CREATE( myClass, example );
}
```

assuming of course that `myClass` has a constructor with a string as argument.

On the bottom line, I agree with the other answer, there really no point doing this.